# Update yaml file containing comments in powershell, possibly within comments

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm attempting to update a yaml file that contains comments in powershell. The field I'm attempting to replace is under 1 heading, but one with the same name might appear in another. Here is an example:

```
yertle: "turtle"

version:
  # ea-nasir: "Sells bad copper"
  foo: bar

database:
  ea-nasir: "Sells bad copper"
  foo: tbol
```

I want to update either `version.foo` or the commented value for `version.ea-nasir` without touching either value in the `database` section.

It needs to work in Powershell 5.1

This what I currently have:

```
( Get-Content -path values.yaml -Raw ) -replace "${key}: .*","${key}: ${version}" | Set-Content -Path values.yaml
```

but it replaces values in `version` and `database`. I was playing around with regex :

```
$key="ea-nasir"
$pattern="version:\n(?:  [#]*[ ]*(${key}: .*).*\n)+"
$version="foo"

( Get-Content -path test.yaml -Raw ) -replace $pattern, "$1  ${key}: ${version}`r`n"
```

but this replaces everything from "version:" down to the captured match.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**:

**As with any *structured text format* such as [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), using a *dedicated parser* is preferable**.

- Unfortunately, as of version 7.3.4, PowerShell has *no* built-in support for parsing YAML - see the relevant feature request in [GitHub issue #3607](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3607).
- However, third-party modules are available, such as [`powershell-yaml`](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml) (install it with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser powershell-yaml`, for istance).

Read on **if you do want to - less robustly - solve the problem with [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based text parsing**:

---

```bash
$section =  'version'       # The top-level property of interest
$key =      'ea-nasir'      # The nested property to update
$newValue = '"new value"'   # The new property value.

(Get-Content -Raw test.yaml)  `
  -replace ('(?xsm) # Regex options: x = IgnorePatternWhiteSpace, s = SingleLine, m = Multiline
             (
                # Capture group for capturing the section and
                # key of interest, not including the value of interest to replace.
               ^{0}:\s*\r?\n      # Start of the section
               .*?                # Section-internal lines preceding the one of interest, if any.
               ^\s+\#?\s*{1}:     # Start of the line with the key of interest
             )
             [^\r\n]*        # The value to replace
            ' -f $section, $key),
            ('$1 {0}' -f $newValue)
```

Note:

- The notable inline [regex option](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) used above is `x` (`IgnorePatternWhitespace`), which allows use of insignificant whitespace for readability as well as `#`-prefixed to-end-of-line comments.

  - As a result, `#` chars. that should be considered *part of the regex pattern*  must be escaped as `\#`, as shown above.
- `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) is used to substitute the variable values for the `{0}` placeholders in the regex / substitution expressions *as-is*; however, for full robustness:

  - In order for values to *predictably* be included *verbatim*, *escaping* is needed:

    - In the *regex*: via [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)
    - In the *substitution expression* of `-replace`: via
      `.Replace('$', '$$')`
- For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/0WTgRh/1), but note that:

  - For brevity, the regex is single-line and doesn't include comments.
  - Of necessity, the values of what are variables above are *hard-coded*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to have to dig into those regexes as they are at least 5 levels above my own XD

That only gives me the updated version block, but adapting it slightly to replace the first with the second seems to work:

```
$Content=Get-Content -Raw values.yaml
$Versions=$Content -replace '(?sm)\A.+^(version:.+?)(?:^\w+:$.*)?\Z','$1'
$UpdatedVersions=$Versions -replace ('(?m)^( +#? *{0}:).*' -f [regex]::Escape($key)), ('$1 {0}' -f $version.Replace('$', '$$'))

Set-Content -Path updated-values.yaml -Value ($Content -replace $Versions, $UpdatedVersions).Trim("`r").Trim("`n")
```

Comment: @diemwing, good point about my original solution only updating _part_ of the whole YAML document. I've fundamentally rewritten the answer - it now uses a _single_ `-replace` operation.